# how to redirect to different user pages after login in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I’m developing a login, i need to login users and **redirect them to their relevant interfaces** after validating the user, i can’t understand how to redirect them to their respective interfaces in CI, how to do that? can you please help me out? if you can give a code and tell the answer it would be great…!

regards,
Rangana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
redirect("/controller/function/parameter");
```

In my application:

```
redirect("/member/view/$userid");
```

More info on the [URL helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: Actually, I don't think there's a "/" at the beginning. It should start with the controller name.

Comment: You wouldn't use the leading slash if you prefaced the URL with base_url().  I use absolute pathing throughout my application.  I'm not saying that my way is the best way.  I'm simply saying that my way works without any discernable problems